# Trying to send the user's value to another HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

How to send user'name from a HTML file to another HTML file and show it on the site?

this is inside the HomePage

```
    <div class="enterUserName" data-validate = "Enter username">
                        <input class="input1" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Player Name">
                        <span class="hi" data-placeholder="&#xe82a;"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="container-login102">
                        <button type="button"class="login" onclick="location.href='Index.html'">
                            Start Playing
                        </button>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried with sessions?

Comment: Do you want to save it, like in a database or just show it for the session, like local storage?

Comment: just to show it local storage

Comment: Try some of these https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp you'll just need to attach it to a click event and make the input a variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you could implement it with [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage):

```html
<div class="enterUserName" data-validate="Enter username">
  <input id="input1" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Player Name">
  <button onclick="saveUserName()">Save</button>
  <button onclick="getUserName()">display</button>
  <span class="hi" data-placeholder="&#xe82a;"></span>
</div>
<div class="container-login102">
  <button type="button" class="login" onclick="location.href='Index.html'">
            Start Playing
        </button>
</div>
<p id="display"></p>

<script>
  function saveUserName() {
    localStorage.setItem('userName', document.getElementById('input1').value)
  }

  function getUserName() {
    if (localStorage.userName) { // userName exists 
      document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = localStorage.userName;
    }
  }
</script>
```

However, when using localStorage, the value is accessible only on the same origin, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy), otherwise you'll need a server-side proxy.

Comment: I get errors when trying to execute your JavaScript. `{
  "message": "SecurityError: The operation is insecure.",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 30,
  "colno": 0
}`

Comment: @Joeri, see [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345385/why-are-we-disallowed-to-use-html5-local-storage-on-code-snippets)

Comment: thanks, but how to get the sent Variable from the other HTML file (in this case index.html)and draw it?

Comment: Run `localSrorage.userName` in the console on the `index.html`, (after running the `saveUserName()` function on the other page), what is the returned value?